# Get Visual Studio 2022 'Go to' to exclude node_modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When using the 'Go to' feature in VS 2022 (ctrl + ,) how can I get VS to ignore the node_modules folder.
Note that the node_modules folder is already marked as ignored but VS still searches typescript symbols within in.

[image]